# ReportDocument serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, crystal-reports, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a ReportDocument using XML serialization but in vain, that's my code:

```
public String serialiser (ReportDocument rd)
    {
        StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportDocument));
        xs.Serialize(sw, rd);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

NB: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.

I got the following error:

```
An error occurred during the reflection of the type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument'.
```

How could I serialize it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that type is not marked as serializable.  Have you tried doing binary serialization?

```
public static byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T original)
{
    byte[] results;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, original);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        results = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: The serialization works but i get exception when deserializing :      T result = (T)bf.Deserialize(ms); -> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation , it's a  TargetInvocationException

Comment: Is it being deserialized in a different session or on a different server?

Comment: No it's not, i've tried with simple objects it works but the one i need, an exception is arised :/

Comment: It looks like Crystal Reports is not going to allow this.  If you need to save it off somewhere, your best bet is probably to turn it into a PDF or RTF and then serialize that to bytes and put it where you want to keep it.